# DB2 UnLOAD in unicode with two chardelimiter

Tags: db2

I have to create an UNLOAD job for a DB2 table and save the UNload in unicode. That's no problem.
But unfortunately there are contents in the table columns that correspond to the separators.

For example, I would like the combination `#!` as a separator, but I can't do that in unicode.
Can someone tell me how to do this?
Now my statement looks like this:

```
DELIMITED COLDEL X'3B' CHARDEL X'24' DECPT X'2E'  
UNICODE
```

thanks a lot for your help

Comment: The delimiter can be a single character (not two characters). Choose a delimiter that's not present in the data , and use the correct hex code relative to your command encoding and output encoding.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I finally found a character that was not used. It's a shame that you can't use more than one character as a separator, it would save you a lot of searching.
Many greetings

Answer (score 0):

The delimiter can be a single character (not two characters, as you want).

In this case the chosen solution was to find a single character that did not appear in the data.

When that is not possible, consider a non-delimited output format, or a different technique to get the data to the external system (for example via federation or other SQL-based interchange, or XML etc.